# Dynamic array in C# (vb.net snippet)

Tags: c#

```
Private Function getFoo(ByVal _FileInfo As FileInfo) As foo()
    Dim provider As New ExcelStorage(GetType(foo))
    provider.StartRow = 2
    provider.StartColumn = 1
    provider.FileName = _FileInfo.FullName
    Dim res() As foo = provider.ExtractRecords()
    Return res
End Function
```

I have the above code in vb.net that i'm trying to convert to C#. I'm using FileHelper library to extract data from Excel. This is my conversion to C#.

```
public static foo GetFoo(FileInfo fInfo)
{
var provider = new ExcelStorage(typeof(foo));
provider.StartRow = 2;
provider.StartColumn = 1;
provider.FileName = fInfo.FullName;
foo res[] = provider.ExtractRecords();
return res;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here. I'm getting Bad array declator. Do I have to declare the size the array first?

Thanks

edit: I change the code as suggested. However, I'm getting this error.

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'foo[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I though I already set the type to foo in the ExcelStorage as typeof(foo).
Nevermind, I did it with casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo res[] = provider.ExtractRecords();
```

should be

```
foo[] res = provider.ExtractRecords();
```

Similarly, as you are returning an array of `foo`s, the declaration should be:

```
public static foo[] GetFoo(FileInfo fInfo)
```

Answer (score 4):

Should be: `foo[] res = provider.ExtractRecords()`

Answer (score 1):

It's `foo[] res` instead of `foo res[]`.

In VB you can use either the syntax where being an array is a property of the variable:

```
Dim x() As Integer
```

or where being an array is a property of the type:

```
Dim x As Integer()
```

The former makes more sense in VB 6, where arrays are a special kind of varaibles, and the latter makes more sense in VB.NET where arrays are objects.

In C# being an array is always part of the type:

```
int[] x;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# the array syntax is attached to the type and not the variable

```
foo[] res = provider.ExtractRecords();
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you declare array variables like so `Type[] VariableName` not like this `Type VariableName[]`

Answer (score 0):

Plus your method needs to return an array as well

```
public static foo[] GetFoo(FileInfo fInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code:

```
public static foo[] GetFoo(FileInfo fInfo)
{
  var provider = new ExcelStorage(typeof(foo));
  provider.StartRow = 2;
  provider.StartColumn = 1;
  provider.FileName = fInfo.FullName;
  foo[] res = provider.ExtractRecords();
  return res;
}
```